# Wait Indicator when user click submit

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

I have an app with web view, where I display a feedback HTML page, I need just to display a wait indicator when user touch the HTML submit button, and maybe better also to disable the submit button in HTML form.

either a solution from iOS side or HTML/Javascript side will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a form with the name and id "myForm", a button with id "myButton" (that button cannot be of type or name "submit") and an empty div with id "waitMessage" where you could insert a wait message or a gif, then you could use something like this:

```
var myButton1 = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton1.onclick = function (){
   getElementById("waitMessage").innerHTML = "Whatever waiting message or html code you want";
   myButton1.disabled=true;
   document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When an HTML form is submitted all execution on the current page is stopped. You cannot continue execution of a timer script.

Most browsers already display a busy indicator.

Answer (score 2):

iOS includes a control in UIKit for the standard spinner, called `UIActivityIndicatorView`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html. You'll call the startAnimating and stopAnimating methods of the instance to begin and end animation, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an activity indicator programmatically in iOS:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *myIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]];
myIndicator.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
myIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
[self.view addSubview:myIndicator];
```

Then to start/stop it:

```
[myIndicator startAnimating];
[myIndicator stopAnimating];
```

As already said, you do not have to disable the HTML form submit button, there is no further execution on that page.